# Генерация hash MCRYPT на nodejs для payeer

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, хеширование

Подскажите как можно сделать такой hash на nodejs

```
$arParams = array(
    'success_url' => 'http://domain.com/new_success_url',
);

$key = md5('Key for encryption additional parameters'.$m_orderid);

$m_params = urlencode(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, json_encode($arParams), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
```

это так хешируются параметры в payeer
urlencode и base64_encode понятно как делать а вот MCRYPT не очень

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcrypt

Comment: Спасибо за модуль